# cannot convert anonymous enum in initialization

Tags: c++, templates, enums, traits

Why does the compiler complain here?

```
  enum jit_ptx_type {f32=0,f64=1,u16=2,u32=3,u64=4,s16=5,s32=6,s64=7,u8=8,b16=9,b32=10,b64=11,pred=12 };

  //
  // MATCHING C TYPES TO PTX TYPES
  //
  template<class T> struct jit_type {};
  template<> struct jit_type<float>            { enum { value = jit_ptx_type::f32 }; };
  template<> struct jit_type<double>           { enum { value = jit_ptx_type::f64 }; };
  template<> struct jit_type<int>              { enum { value = jit_ptx_type::s32 }; };
  template<> struct jit_type<bool>             { enum { value = jit_ptx_type::pred }; };
```

later in the code:

```
  some_func( float val ) {
    jit_ptx_type type = jit_type<float>::value;   // compiler complains here
  }
```

Compiler message:

```
error: cannot convert ‘jit_type<float>::<anonymous enum>’ to ‘jit_ptx_type’ in assignment
```

It's strange! If I put these lines into a separate small example file it works.

Comment: Unscoped enums don't use qualification. I'd use `static constexpr int value = ...;`, though.

Comment: I mean instead of using `jit_ptx_type::f32`, you need `f32`, or to use `enum class` instead. It seems unrelated to the error at first glance, though, even though it's invalid syntax.

Comment: Still the same compiler message.

Comment: Does it work with a static constant member instead of an anonymous enum with one value?

Comment: Yes, it does work with `static constexpr jit_ptx_type value = f32;` Then it must have been the additional `enum`. However, in a cut-out example it works with `enum`. That's the strange thing about it. However, many thanks! Do you think in general the very first line as posted here is okay? Or should I use a enum class as you said?

Comment: It's generally better to use `enum class` so you don't pollute the surrounding scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for making the outer enum into a scoped enum:

```
enum class jit_ptx_type {
    f32=0, //note the =x is unnecessary here
    f64=1,
    u16=2,
    u32=3,
    u64=4,
    s16=5,
    s32=6,
    s64=7,
    u8=8,
    b16=9,
    b32=10,
    b64=11,
    pred=12 
};
```

Now you don't pollute the surrounding scope with all of those identifiers and you need scope qualifiers to access the values, whereas unscoped enums disallow that. Next, in your class, just use a static constant member:

```
template<> struct jit_type<float> { 
    static constexpr value = jit_ptx_type::f32; 
};
```